# Zapier, specifying both a querystring and a parameter.

Tags: zapier

I have 2 keys (api key, sub key), one is a querystring parameter, the other is a header. In Zapier, in an app that you've already created, you can "Manage Authentication Settings", and whether you have one Header Key, and a Querystring key, a username, a pass, you only have one "Manage Authentication Settings" button.

Inside the Manage menu, you can select settings that are then applied to ALL FIELDS AT ONCE. You can select the Auth Type, either ApiKey(querystring), or ApiKey(headers), one or the other, but you cannot designate one field as being a querystring, and the other field as a header. On the bottom, you can select the Access Token Placement. Whether, header, querystring, or both, again, applied to all auth fields.

So far as I can tell, the "Both" token placement does nothing.

Long story short, I need to specify which one is the header, and which one is the query string. Currently, the querystring side is working fine, and I'm getting an error from our server for the header being missing. Is this something that can be done in Zapier? If so, how?